# Firebase import array data to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have tableview in VC and I would like  to import "Detail" item form current recipe:

[Firebase entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6E9Y.png)

to tableView - each to a separate cell.

**My Code in RecipiesModel:**

```
class RecipiesModel {

    var title: String?
    var desc: String?
    var detail: Array<Any>?

    init(title: String?, desc: String?, detail: Array<Any>?){
        self.title = title
        self.desc = desc
        self.detail = detail
    }
}
```

**My Code in VC:**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class DescriptionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var textInput: String = ""
    var descInput: String = ""

    var ref:DatabaseReference!
    var recipiesList = [RecipiesModel]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabelDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabelDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tabBarView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        customUIView()

        titleLabelDesc.text = textInput
        descriptionLabelDesc.text = descInput

        loadList()
    }

    //Database

    func loadList() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Recipies").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let results = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            let title = results?["Recipies title"]
            let desc = results?["Recipies description"]
            let detail = results?["Detail"]
            let myRecipies = RecipiesModel(title: title as! String?, desc: desc as! String?, detail: detail as! Array<Any>?)
            self.recipiesList.append(myRecipies)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    func customUIView() {
        tabBarView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        tabBarView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        tabBarView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        tabBarView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    }

    @IBAction func dismissButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //TableView

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipiesList.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellDescription") as! TableViewCellDescription

        let recipies = recipiesList[indexPath.row]
        cell.recipiesModuleLabel.text = recipies.detail?.description

        return cell
    }
}
```

At this moment the result is:

[Table View Entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1V3q.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you want your data to be shown? Each of your `RecipiesModel ` object will have different `Array` of details. How do you want to distinguish among them if you just put them in an ordered list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you want to show details items in different row whereas you have array of `RecipiesModel`.

```
var recipiesList = [RecipiesModel]()
```

In case you can represent each `modal object of array` as a section and `details` object as their rows. You can do that as:

```
// TableView datasource and delegate methods

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return recipiesList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let modal = recipiesList[section]
    return "\(modal.title ?? ""): \(modal.desc ?? "")"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recipiesList[section].detail?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellDescription") as! TableViewCellDescription
    if let detailName = recipiesList[indexPath.section].detail?[indexPath.row] as? String {
        cell.recipiesModuleLabel.text = detailName
    } else {
        cell.recipiesModuleLabel.text = ""
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: In tableview everything is perfectly - thanks! I have one more problem - from the database are importing the details of all recipes instead of one. What error do I have in the retrieve code from the database?